# How to switch a value from HTML variable inside a view from Ember.TextField?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, ember.js

I've been wondering how in **Ember.js** is possible to change a value from a **HTML** variable. What I am trying to do is when I *click* on a *edit button*, I'd like to change the value of **readonly** and make it readable on a textfield using the view Ember.TextField.

The code is showed bellow:

```
<div id="list_container">
    <h2>Contacts:</h2>
    <ul id="people_List">
    {{#each person in controller}}
     <li {{bindAttr class='isEditing:red'}}>
           <!-- here where Im trying to use the value to switch the value from a html variable -->
           {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="person.name" readonly='isEditing'}}
           {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="person.birthday" readonly='isEditing'}}
           {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="person.telephone" readonly='isEditing'}}
           <button {{action edit}}>Edit</button>
           <button {{action details}}>Details</button>
           <button {{action remove}}>Remove</button>
     </li>
     {{/each}}
     </ul>
</div>

Schedule.PeopleController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'Person'
});

Schedule.PersonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: true,
    edit : function () {
        this.toggleProperty('isEditing');
        console.log(this.get('isEditing'));
    },
    details : function () {
        console.log("Details was clicked!!");
    },
    remove : function () {
        console.log("Remove was clicked!!");
    }
});
```

I'm avoiding the use of:

```
{{if}}
...HTML CODE...
{{else}}
...HTML CODE...
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind the readonly attribute to the textfield view.

You can do so by creating a custom textfield view extending Ember.TextField

```
Source.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
      attributeBindings: ["readonly"]
})
```

in your handlebars

```
   {{view Source.TextField valueBinding="person.name" readonlyBinding='isEditing'}}
   {{view Source.TextField valueBinding="person.birthday" readonlyBinding='isEditing'}}
   {{view Source.TextField valueBinding="person.telephone" readonlyBinding='isEditing'}}
```

or to add support globally reopen `Ember.TextField` or `Ember.TextSupport`.

```
Ember.TextSupport.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ["readonly"]
})
```

and in your handlebars

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="person.name" readonlyBinding='isEditing'}}
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="person.birthday" readonlyBinding='isEditing'}}
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="person.telephone" readonlyBinding='isEditing'}}
```

Actually

> By default Ember.TextField provides support for type, value, size, pattern, placeholder, disabled, maxlength and tabindex attributes on a text field.If you need to support more attributes you have to do one of the above.

Refer [this](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html) API Documentation for more details

Comment: On **readonlyBinding='isEditing'** is possible to invert the value which is being passed as parameter? I've been thinking in something like this: **readonlyBinding='#not isEditing'**

Comment: I'm not sure, if there is such thing, but you can have a computed property in your itemController, which will return the negotiation of isEditing, observing isEditing, like `isNotEditing: function(){return !this.get('isEditing')}.property('isEditing')` and give that as binding to readonly, as `readonlyBinding='isNotEditing'`

Answer (score 1):

The Hyder aswer is correct. In addition here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/q4Pcr/)

Just provide the `attributeBindings: ["readonly"]`, to your view.
And that atribute will respond to changes.